# A clarification on GNU licence

Tags: open-source, cygwin, licensing, gnu, redhat

I am using Cygwin to compile a third party application called iPerf.exe that I am using as a plug-in to my application. We are planning to distribute this application to our users. I know that GNU licence agreement of cygwin says that if you are planning to compile your application using cygwin then please be ready to make your code open source.

I am not compiling our entire application using cygwin. I using cygwin because we are using iperf.exe which was written for Linux. I had to change some of the source code and re-compile it in Windows to produce windows executable.

Here is my question:

Under GNU licence, do I have to release the iPerf.exe code that I have changed or I have to release the entire application code? I would not be allowed to release entire application code so I hope releasing my changes to iPerf.exe should be suffice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2):

If your `iperf.exe` is linked against `cygwin1.dll`, then you must either release it under an OSI-approved license (as well as providing the sources for Cygwin itself if you distribute that too) or purchase a license buyout from Red Hat, as described [here](http://cygwin.com/license.html).

As for your application which uses iperf as a "plugin", that depends on the connection between the two; you'll need to be more specific to get a clear answer.

Comment: So my application is used to send data packet over the TCP/IP. for this purpose we are using iPerf.exe plug-in. That is what functionality that iPerf brought into our application. My application does a lot of test cases(10-15) but only one test case used iPerf.exe. That is proportion to which iPerf.exe is relevant.

Comment: If that test-case is part of your program - as you just described it - then you don't have two separate programs here. That might make you require to release all under GPLv3+ and as you wrote you can't, then you need to obtain the buy-out license: http://www.redhat.com/services/custom/cygwin/